# How to load Multiple excel source files with different structure into a target table in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to load a target table (Daily truncate and load ) using excel files as source and these excel files have different names to it like Plan code Mappings - API or Plan code Mappings - Main Frame . The excel structure is also varying , for example one source has 2 column and another has 4. Please let me know on how this can be achieved using Informatica Power center 10.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a generic structure with max number of columns. for your example its 4.

1. create a shell script to create a list of those xl files.
2. create a new list file with all xlsx file.
3. create a session with a source with above max columns. ANd the map them to correct targets as per your understanding and filename etc.
4. delete files once loaded.

Now, i would recommend to use csv file and convert xl file to csv file for easy reading. for xlsx you need to use data direct driver, create new ODBC DSN and use it.

Comment: @kaushik Roy If we are using a source file in loading, and the source file name change daily so how do we handle this without changing the file name manually daily?
for example: if the file name is changing depending on a date so what should I do?

Comment: Good question. Normally when you create a list file you list them using a pattern using wildcard(`*`). so you create file list using this pre session shell command `ls -1 AP_FILE_*.csv > file_list.txt`

Comment: thanks for the inputs , but we don't use a Linux environment and its based out of windows , how can I handle this scenario there ?

Comment: Use `dir /b /a-d file*.csv > file_list.txt` for WINDOWS.

Answer (score 1):

Tere is no way in PowerCenter to read Excel files with different structures with one mapping if using ODBC connector where Excel file needs to have named area that PowerCenter connects to.

The only way would be to create a source definiton generic enough to describe all the 4 different structures and processing data with some generic ports depending on the file name or content. This will be though to create and even harder to maintain in the long run.

Instead, you should create 4 tailored mappings, each one matching the needs and structure.